# "Klugscheißer"?

Tags: translation, slang

Does Japanese have a term more-or-less equivalent to the German *Klugscheißer* (literally, "clever-shitter"; in English: smartypants, smartass, know-it-all, etc.)?

(Needless to say, this is not a term suitable for polite conversation!)

The best I could do was to look for translations for "smartass" or "smartypants".  All I got this way was 賢い人, which, AFAIK, is not considered particularly vulgar, and does not even carry the derogatory/mocking overtones of the *Klugscheißer*.  (But please correct me if I'm wrong!)

P.S. If you found an online source for this translation, *please include it in your answer!*  I had no success with the many I tried, including a [short video](http://www.wdr.de/tv/wissenmachtah/bibliothek/klugscheissen.php5#sofFlashVideoBox) entirely devoted to equivalents in various languages (but *not* in Japanese).

Comment: There's an entry on ALC: http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=smarty-pants&ref=sa

Answer (score 2):

In French, this has two meanings. Both conveys that the person is irritating but one is "clever for real", one is "pretending to be".

For the "pretending to be clever", you have [`知ったかぶり`](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/98579/m0u/).

Comment: Well, it's got the sh*t part... :)  I think that calling someone a *Klugscheißer* is not so much a comment on whether the person's knowledge is for real, as it is a way to tell someone that the sentiment his/her knowledge induces in others is irritation rather than admiration.