# Meaning of どこの ( + noun)?

Tags: meaning

I found Shimazaki Touson's work 'shiawase', and read the first few lines:

> 「幸せ」が色々な家へたずねて行きました。だれでも幸せの欲しくないひとはありませんから、どこの家をたずねましても、みんな大喜びでむかえてくれるに違いありません。

My question is how I can translate

> どこの家?

I understand that "doko" means "where", but in this position I can't imagine how to interpret.
Thank you for reading my question.

Answer (score 7):

The [question word]+[verb in ～て form]+[particle も] construction is usually translated as whoever, wherever, whatever, whichever etc.

Some other examples would be

> 誰に聞いても、答えは誰も知らなかった。
> Whoever we asked, nobody knew the answer.
>
> 何をしても、駄目だった。
> Whatever I did, it was hopeless.
>
> どんな例文を書いても、構文は一緒です。
> Whichever example I write, the sentence structure is the same.

Now, in your sentence:

> どこの家をたずねましても、みんな大喜びでむかえてくれるに違いありません。
> Whichever house we visited, everyone would receive us with open arms without fail.

or something that makes more sense in the context.

Comment: The `たずねる` in this context is more likely `訪ねる` which is "to visit", instead of `尋ねる` ("ask/inquire").

Comment: @Earthling, what is your native language?

Comment: Let me guess... ドイツ語！

Comment: Really?  I always assumed it was English!

Comment: @Chocolate Hehe, if my account wasn't affiliated with German.SE, your guess would have been truly remarkable. What gave me away?

Comment: @Earthling えへへ！これです～^^ http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/9844/klugschei%C3%9Fer/9849#9849

Comment: @Earthling, just curious.

Comment: But it would be nice to know what the difference in nuance is between どこの家 and どの家. Is どこ permitted here because houses have physical locations? Would it also be possible to say どこのひとに聞いても in general reference to "anyone" (even if not focused on a person's physical location)? My sense is that どこの can in fact be used as a general replacement for どのhere, but to me it has a colloquial feel or may even be a dialect. On another note, どこの家をたずねましても、みんな大喜びでむかえてくれるに違いありません。 is referring to 幸せ, so I guess a better translation would be "any house it visits will certainly greet it with open arms".

Comment: @torazaburo どの=which, どこの="of where". どこ is asking for a location, so どこの人 is asking for people from different locations. どこのひとに聞いても=wherever I asked (people).