# Meaning of 俺はどこまで行っても俺だ

Tags: meaning

Looking for some help understanding **俺はどこまで行っても俺だ**.

I've googled and can see the phrase どこまで行っても being used fairly often, but can't find an explanation, and what definition of 行く is being used here.

Comment: Highly related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/12128/7944

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 「俺{おれ}はどこまで行{い}っても俺だ。」

is almost like a set phrase meaning:

> "I will always be me."

「どこまで行っても」 literally means "**no matter where I go**" and it can also figuratively mean "**eternally**" or "**till the end of time**".

Whether the 'movement' is spatial or temporal is of little importance here unless the context this expression appears in clearly specifies one over the other.  To Japanese-speakers, 「どこまで行っても」 is fairly synonymous to 「いつまでも」、「何があっても」、「どんな時でも」, etc., which is why "I will always be me." should cover them all in most cases.